# Creation of a heaptree using an array

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, heap

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Enode{
    private: 
    int data;
    Enode* left;
    Enode* right;
    
    
    Enode(int d){
        data = d;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
    
    friend class Heaptree;
    
};

//MAX HEAP STRUCTURE, ROOT NODE IS MAX

class Heaptree{
    private:
    Enode* root;
    
    public:
    Heaptree(){
        root = NULL;
    }
    
    Enode* createHeapTree(int arr[], int idx, int n, Enode* root1){
        if(idx>=n){
            return NULL;
        }
        
        root1 = new Enode(arr[idx]);
        
        if((2*idx + 1)<n){
            root->left = createHeapTree(arr, 2*idx + 1, n, root1->left);
        }
        
        if((2*idx + 2)<n){
            root->right = createHeapTree(arr, 2*idx + 2, n, root1->right);
        }
        
        return root1;
    }
    
    Enode* getRoot(){
        return root;
    }
    
    void printLevelOrder(){
        Enode* temp;
        queue <Enode*> Q;
        Q.push(root);
        while(!Q.empty()){
            temp = Q.front();
            cout<<temp->data;
            Q.pop();
            if(temp->left!=nullptr){
                Q.push(temp->left);
            }
            
            if(temp->right!=nullptr){
                Q.push(temp->right);
            }
        }
    }
    
};

void heapify(int arr[], int n){
    int t, left, right;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        left = 2*i+1;
        right = 2*i + 2;
        // cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
        if(left<n && arr[left]>arr[i]){
            t = arr[i];
            arr[i]= arr[left];
            arr[left] = t;
        }
        
        if(right <n && arr[right]>arr[i]){
            t = arr[i];
            arr[i]= arr[right];
            arr[right] = t;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    Heaptree h1;
    Enode* Root;
    cin>>n;
    int comparray[n];
    for(int i =0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>comparray[i];
    }
    
    heapify(comparray, n);
    
    for(int i =0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<comparray[i];
    }
    
    Root = h1.getRoot();
    Root = h1.createHeapTree(comparray, 0, n, Root);
    h1.printLevelOrder();
    
    return 0;
}
```

I coded this to create a `MaxHeap` tree from an array. The `Heapify` function works correctly.

But code doesn't successfully create a `heaptree` and I am unable to identify where I am going wrong.

There seems to be something wrong with the `createHeaptree` function but I can't figure out what that is. I think I am going out of bounds with some index, or I am not accessing the root correctly.

But I am unable to identify where exactly I'm going wrong.

Comment: You do realize that C++ [already has this functionality](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap)?  You simply fill the array, call `std::make_heap` and bingo, you have a max heap.

Comment: 1) `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- This is a non-standard header.  Do not use it.   2) `cin>>n; int comparray[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  An array in C++ must have its size denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime variable.  This should be `std::vector<int> comparray(n);`

Comment: You pass `root1` as a parameter but immediately overwrite its value. It is also always the null pointer. What is the point of the parameter?

Comment: Note that assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument has no effect outside that function. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this may be some coding assignment from school/university, so using a built-in method is not always a solution ...

Comment: @derpirscher The school is teaching bad C++, given the `bits` header and VLA's.  It looks more like something from an online "competitive coding" website.